# Mute JWPlayer silverlight using Javascript

Tags: javascript, silverlight, jwplayer

There is a way to mute/unmute JWPlayer (silverlight version) using Javascript like the Flash/HTML5 versions?

I can't find documentation about the silverlight version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, we have some old docs here available on archive.org:

http://web.archive.org/web/20080705154841/http://code.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/SLVars
http://web.archive.org/web/20080805163326/http://code.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/SLAPI